# Error when running unit tests when assigning a task owner id to a queue

Tags: apex, queue

```
public static void updateTasks(List<ID> recordIds) {  
    Group queue = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM Group
        WHERE Name = 'Queue Name'
        AND Type = 'Queue'
    ];
    // Id queueId = Id.valueof(queue.Id);
    // Get those records based on the IDs
    List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Task WHERE Id IN :recordIds];
    for (Task tsk : tasks) {
        tsk.OwnerId = queue.Id;
    }
    // Process records
    update tasks;
}
```

System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00T1100000NqvuEEAR; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Assigned To ID: id value of incorrect type: 00G110000041kxOEAQ: [OwnerId]

**I have tried it using the Id.valueOf and not using it and the result is the same**

1. I have the Task object as a supported object in my queue settings.

Comment: The Queue needs to be able to own Tasks.

Comment: I have the Task object as a supported object in my queue.

Comment: What API version is the class on? Needs to be v48.0 or higher I think

Comment: Just checked and its on 49.0

Comment: This problem is only for unit test? How about when you run the code in Execute Anonymouse Window?

Comment: @hdev was your problem resolved? I am facing same error

Comment: Thanks @Instread - upping the API version to "v52.0" fixed this for my code :)